# condition for only if is archive for default post type

Tags: archives

In order to optimize my site for a bit more loading speed, I wanted to enqueue a couple of scripts only to the archives for default post type. A rough example is given below.

```
function my_theme_script_enqueues() {

        if (!is_admin()) {

            if ( is_archive()) {
                wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', 'jquery');
                wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
            }
        }
    }

add_action (blah..blah..blah..blah)
```

I assumed something like (is_archive('post')) would work, but it still loads on cpt-archive and tag archives and such ( does not load on pages though).

I cant use `(is_archive())` as it again loads it to every other archive types eg. cpt-archives, tags etc which is pointless to me.

If I use if `(!is_post_type_archive('cpt')) {...}` then it obviously goes wild and loads it everywhere else, not scalable.

I know how to use if`( is_post_type_archive('post')) {...}`, but it is not giving me any result, which it should i guess as 'post' is a post-type right? When I search for a solution here I get mostly threads talking about custom post type archive. Please let me know what my alternative is?

Comment: Hi..When I said _I wanted to enqueue a couple of scripts only to the archives for default post type_, I actually meant that I only wanted it load only on default post type **categories**. But seems like I overly complicated the question which led to the (is_home()) possibility, which was not my case. I apologize.
(is_category()) was a simple and so obvious solution for me.  I knew I was missing something obvious.
God, I feel so stupid. !
Salute to all the great folks for help anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_archive()` doesn't accept any parameter and return true for every archive page: Categories, tag, date, author, .... I think what you need is to check if you are in a [category page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) (in a archive of the category taxonomy) or in the blog home:

```
if ( is_category() || is_home() ) {
    wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
 }
```

Comment: Yes, (is_category()) did the trick. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Doesn't this miss is_tag() etc features of the is_archive()? I find it perplexing I can't use is_post_type_archive( "post" ) to differentiate between blog posts and other post types.

Comment: The standard post archive is the blog home page, so I think `is_home()` is the conditional you should use for `is_post_type_archive( "post" )` but if you are in a tag, category, date or author archive you will need to add the proper conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `is_home()`.

It's inconsistent for historical reason. Concept of post type archives hadn't appeared until after there were actually custom post types to have archives for.

The basic index list of blog posts is `is_home()` and somewhat confusingly it's not even `is_archive()`.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Always thinked `is_home()` works if posts page is setted. Upvoted for teach me this.

Comment: @G.M. yeah, the naming and logic around `is_home()`/`is_front_page()` is unholy mess. The _modern meaning_ for `is_home()` is archive of `post` post type, but it's neither called that, neither archive. _sigh_

Comment: What confused me is the fact that activating pretty permalinks there is no way to have a *generic* archive of standard post type without setting the posts page. Sure `home_url()` works... until I set a front static page.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here via Google looking for a solution for *all* archives using the default `post` post type. Here's how to accomplish that:

Per @Rarst's answer, `is_archive()` doesn't work because it misses anything that fulfills the `is_home()` condition. And per the question itself, `is_archive()` also fails in this scenario because it returns true for CPT archives.

This should work:

```
if(get_post_type() == 'post' && !is_single()) {
    ...
}
```

`get_post_type` will return `post` for the "Posts Page" or any other archives or singular endpoints that are querying the `post` post type, and then `!is_single()` will skip the singular endpoints.